# Design Roller Compacted Concrete Pavement Section

Tags: civil-engineering, concrete, pavement

I have been asked to consider using RCC instead of traditional PCC on an upcoming project. For a rough order of magnitude estimate, can I assume that the pavement section design will be similar? I know that the mix design and construction methods will vary, but not sure if there will be any difference in the thickness of concrete or aggregate base.

Answer (score 3):

RCCPave is the pavement design software tool for RCC, this is the guide that supports the software.  http://members.cement.org/EBiz55/ProductCatalog/Product.aspx?ID=1626

I can’t find a download for the software though, must need to contact ACPA.

Answer (score 2):

Pavement ME does not have an RCC pavement design module so using it to design RCC is not within the bounds of the design procedure.

If we are talking general pavement performance principles, there is some similarity between RCC and undoweled jointed concrete pavement. You could use Pavement ME to look at the potential slab cracking for jointed concrete and expect some similarity with RCC.  Looking at roughness would be more of a stretch.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on roller compacted concrete but I did find a few links to reports on the topic. They are listed below.

- [FHWA Tech Brief on RCC](https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/pavement/pub_details.cfm?id=993)
- [National Concrete Pavement Technology Center Guide for RCC Pavements](https://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=&httpsredir=1&article=1100&context=intrans_reports)
- [Portland Cement Association RCC Page](https://www.cement.org/cement-concrete-applications/paving/roller-compacted-concrete-(rcc))
- [RCC Pavement Council Resources Page](http://rccpavementcouncil.org/category/resources/)

I hope you are able to find some useful information in the links above.